# SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF

Tags: php, javascript, syntax-error, line-breaks

I add this code into my `php` footer:
When I use the same syntax in an HTML document everything works well for me.

```
   <body>
    ...

        <script type="text/javascript">     

        // Browser detection
        function checkBrowserName(name){ 
        var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();  
        if (agent.indexOf(name.toLowerCase())>-1) {  
        return true;  
        }  
        return false;  
        }  

        if(checkBrowserName('opera')){
        /* load nothing */
        }

        else if(checkBrowserName('')) {
        /* else if(checkBrowserName('firefox') || ('msie') || ('safari') || ('konqueror') || ('omniweb') || ('webtv') || ('icab') || ('compatible')) { */

        // Insert script
        document.write('<script src="assets/javascripts/hyphenate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
        document.write('<\/script>');

        // Script options
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript">');
        document.write('Hyphenator.config({');
        document.write('displaytogglebox : false,');
        document.write('minwordlength : 4');
        document.write('});');
        document.write('Hyphenator.run();');
        document.write('<\/script>');

        }
        </script>
    ...
    </body>
```

Is something wrong with my line-breaks?

When I write the code like this, it will work for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascripts/hyphenate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

Hyphenator.config({
    displaytogglebox : false,
    minwordlength : 4
});
Hyphenator.run();

</script>
```

Thanks for your help
Ogni

Comment: Sometimes invalid characters can work their way into code when you copy/paste code from websites.

Comment: How/where/when do you call checkBrowserName() ?

Comment: I don't see any PHP in your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot write `</script>` into strings, because parsing ends at this point then.
Just escape it:

```
document.write('<script src="assets/javascripts/hyphenate.min.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
```

(like you did the other times...)