# "SintaxisError: Unexpected EOF" is showed in console

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error:

[image]

I'm not sure what I have wrong in my index.html. I am currently developing an app on ionic1 and this error is generated when I try to inspect my code by safari. I have read that this error occurs when a label is not closed, but in my case I do not know what I have wrong. What can be?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>

        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />

        <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
        <script>
          if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
              .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
              .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
          }
        </script>-->

        <!-- css -->
        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/utilities.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/font-awesome/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/animate/animate.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/waves/css/waves.css" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/swiper/css/swiper.css" />

        <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
        <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
        -->

        <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

        <script src="lib/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

        <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/ngStorage/js/ngStorage.js"></script>

        <!-- your app's js -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services.js"></script>
        <script src="js/constantes.js"></script>


        <!-- libs -->
        <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/moment/moment.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/swiper/js/swiper.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/prefixfree/js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

        <!--<script src='lib/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js'></script>-->
        <!--<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyANNBvPehUvWndNs7zmVqWa7ys1DBTQnDs"></script>-->

        <!-- Controladores TinApp -->
        <script src="js/controllers/login/loginController.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="js/controllers/wizard/ubicacionTinController.js"></script>-->
        <script src="js/controllers/wizard/instructivoTinController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/wizard/recuperarContrasenaController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/registros/registrarUsuariosController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/ofertas/ofertasController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/ofertas/descripcionOfertaController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/negocios/negocioController.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="js/controllers/negocios/productosController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/negocios/descripcionProductoController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/favoritos/favoritosController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/favoritos/descripcionFavoritoController.js"></script>-->
        <script src="js/controllers/cupones/cuponesController.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/cupones/misCuponesController.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="js/controllers/tins/misTinsController.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script src="js/controllers/ajustes/ajustesController.js"></script>-->
        <script src="js/controllers/ubicaciones/ubicacionesController.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body ng-app="tinApp">
        <ion-nav-view class="viewport_inicial"></ion-nav-view>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It would better if you post your `index.html` out here

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I updated the code, thanks

Comment: is it working fine on other browsers?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12976823/7124761

Comment: This one also:https://stackoverflow.com/a/26325623/7124761

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element):

> The title element must not be empty.

Just add a `title`:

```
<title>tinApp</title>
```